# python - pip installs but cannot import

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I've read a lot of posts about this but none of the solutions have worked for me. I'm trying to get a module called nsxramlclient installed, shows successful installation with pip but cannot import from any location outside of the /Users/Nathan/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages.

Uninstall does work after some fidgeting with brew using the recommendations found with brew doctor. Here are some vitals:

Running OSX python 2.7.10

PIP 18.1

```
which -a pip = /usr/local/bin/pip

which -a python = shows 2 directories:
 /usr/local/bin/python
 /usr/bin/python
```

**python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'**
['', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload']

```
pip list | grep nsxramlclient
nsxramlclient        2.0.7
```

It has to be a path issue since I'm able to import it from the directory that the module is located. I just don't know the proper method to repair this since I'm fairly new to Python and I don't want to mess it up worse that it is already.

Comment: Try `python -m pip install`... But, basically, `/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1` means you're not using Python 2.7.10 or `Library/Python/2.7/lib/`... You could also try a virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I did end up getting it to work finally. What I had to do was to re-install python with brew:

```
brew re-install python@2
```

then I needed to re-install the modules I needed with pip. Having OTHER issues now but at least this one is fixed.